# Please reopen "Trick circumvents [position: sticky] restriction to parent"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

[Trick circumvents [position: sticky] restriction to parent](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/201327)

My question was put on hold. Please vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it seems that the issue is that you needed to have content in the HTML enough to make it scroll before the button.

I have added a stack snippet example that works for me and reopened the question.